# Linear geometric transformations with application to IFS fractals

Tags: fractals

I am one of the developers of Perceptron http://perceptron.sourceforge.net - unique generator of video-feedback fractals written in Java. I would like to draw your attention to this open-source project, so that you may also participate in the forum at SourceForge web site.

In particular, I am interested to improve the current linear geometric transformations.

What Perceptron generates is always an IFS fractal made of fragments of a Julia fractal. Such combination is created in a two-step, cyclic (recursive, endless) process of image transformation:

morphing according to z_new = f(z_old) + constant_c
and a linear mapping.

In file DoubleBuffer.java, we read the pixel color from the "screen" at the coordinates given by 
z_new = (x,y).

Naturally, the complex number z_new can be anywhere in the complex plane, but the "screen" has strict physical dimensions. The desired coordinates HAVE been scaled to the screen appropriately - that is not the issue.

However, we apply seemingly needless rules such as, "take absolute value of z_new", or, "if z_new is large, wrap it!". We apply these rules to prevent reading non-existent off-screen pixels. Instead, we re-read some of the pixels. This leads to the amazing IFS fractals.

I want to know where can I learn more similar "linear geometric transformations" that wrap arrays (matrices) in interesting ways, create tiles, rotations, shape the data in matrices by giving them edges of various shapes, transformations that simulate mirrors and such.

To illustrate, see this code.

```
public int interface_getColor(int x, int y) {
 /**
  * Only positive x and y at the screen can be read to obtain
  * the color.  */

 x ^= x >> 31;   // absolute values only; no choice but to disregard negative z_new
 y ^= y >> 31;

 x >>= 8;    //divide by 256
 y >>= 8;

 /**
  * The reflection transformation to put the off-screen z_new
  * points back within the screen. Although x = x % W and y =
  * y % H would suffice, it is more interesting like this...        */

  x = (x / W & 1) == 0 ? x % W : W_ONE - x % W;   // if x/W is even then x =... else x=...
  y = (y / H & 1) == 0 ? y % H : H_ONE - y % H;   

 /**
  * Since the screen is a one-dimensional array of length
  * W*H, the index of any element is i(x,y) = x + W * y.  */

  return buffer.getElem(x + W * y);
}
```

As you can see, bitwise operators are required for speed and classical array wrapping gives more wonder than anyone had ever hoped to see from an IFS fractal. It would be good to replace this hard-coded block with equations from a definition file, and a template suggestion is required.

Comment: Schwartz-Christoffel mappings would be cool to have, I guess.

Comment: I'll check what that is in a second! Thanks! You know, I still can't think how to avoid using modulus % function. It is kind of primitive and crude, but it is safe, it does not give errors.